# How do I use the touchscreen on the Lenovo Flex 5 15IIL05 with Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, touchscreen, 20.10

I just got a Lenovo Flex 5 and installed Ubuntu 20.10 on it. I'd like to be able to use the touchscreen, and I was wondering if there was any way to enable it.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:243f Syntek Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`xinput` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Mouse               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```